# What data types can you give as keys to feed in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

Consider computing an inner product in tensor flow for the sake of an example. I was trying to experiment on the different ways to refer to things in graphs in TensorFlow when one evaluates it with a session using feed. Consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

M = 4
D = 2
D1 = 3
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[M, D], name='data_x') # M x D
W = tf.Variable( tf.truncated_normal([D,D1], mean=0.0, stddev=0.1) ) # (D x D1)
b = tf.Variable( tf.constant(0.1, shape=[D1]) ) # (D1 x 1)
inner_product = tf.matmul(x,W) + b # M x D1
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run( tf.initialize_all_variables() )
    x_val = np.random.rand(M,D)
    #print type(x.name)
    #print x.name
    name = x.name
    ans = sess.run(inner_product, feed_dict={name: x_val})
    ans = sess.run(inner_product, feed_dict={x.name: x_val})
    ans = sess.run(inner_product, feed_dict={x: x_val})
    name_str = unicode('data_x', "utf-8")
    ans = sess.run(inner_product, feed_dict={"data_x": x_val}) #doesn't work
    ans = sess.run(inner_product, feed_dict={'data_x': x_val}) #doesn't work
    ans = sess.run(inner_product, feed_dict={name_str: x_val}) #doesn't work
    print ans
```

The following work:

```
ans = sess.run(inner_product, feed_dict={name: x_val})
ans = sess.run(inner_product, feed_dict={x.name: x_val})
ans = sess.run(inner_product, feed_dict={x: x_val})
```

but the last three:

```
name_str = unicode('data_x', "utf-8")
ans = sess.run(inner_product, feed_dict={"data_x": x_val}) #doesn't work
ans = sess.run(inner_product, feed_dict={'data_x': x_val}) #doesn't work
ans = sess.run(inner_product, feed_dict={name_str: x_val}) #doesn't work
```

don't. I checked why type `x.name` was but it still didn't work even when I converted it to the type python interpreter said it was. I [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/client.html#session-management) seems to say that the keys have to be tensors. However, it accepted `x.name` while its not a tensor (its a `<type 'unicode'>`), does someone know whats going on?

---

I can paste the documentation says it need to be a tensor:

> The optional feed_dict argument allows the caller to override the
>   value of tensors in the graph. Each key in feed_dict can be one of the
>   following types:
>
> If the key is a Tensor, the value may be a Python scalar, string,
>   list, or numpy ndarray that can be converted to the same dtype as that
>   tensor. Additionally, if the key is a placeholder, the shape of the
>   value will be checked for compatibility with the placeholder. If the
>   key is a SparseTensor, the value should be a SparseTensorValue. Each
>   value in feed_dict must be convertible to a numpy array of the dtype
>   of the corresponding key.

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow primarily expects `tf.Tensor` objects as the keys in the feed dictionary. It will also accept a string (which may be `bytes` or `unicode`) if it is equal to the `.name` property of some `tf.Tensor` in the session's graph.

In your example, `x.name` works, because `x` is a `tf.Tensor` and you're evaluating its `.name` property. `"data_val"` does not work because it is the name of a `tf.Operation` (viz. `x.op`) and not the name of a `tf.Tensor`, which is the output of a `tf.Operation`. If you print `x.name`, you'll see that it has the value `"data_val:0"`, which means "the 0th output of a `tf.Operation` called `"data_val"`.